# Build is successful, everytime, however development server is closing

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-native

Build is successfully getting run but the development server is closing, as of that my React-native app is not able to run on emulator

[image]

You can check the error on the emulator, kindly do tell me the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` in cmd and it could help you.

Comment: Thank You, but I solved this by uninstalling the node 12 which I had, and installing node 10 lts, that worked for me